# VBA code to combine move cursor + left click + then automatically adding/writing the required values + then executing the rest of task

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Currently I am having a task of automating an Excel addin. This excel addin consist of software worflows of an application.
I have to click on login somewhere on ribbon(for which I need to move the cursor) then I have to click on it(left click). Then a login pop-up will appear in which I have to enter the user name and password and click on proceed button(move and click the left click ->Enter the username and password->Click on proceed). Then I have to check few cells values and show that value in message pop-up.

Few line of VBA code that I tried to...

```
'Declare mouse events
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
'Declare sleep
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub LeftClick(ByVal i As Integer, ByVal j As Integer)

SetCursorPos i, j 'x and y position
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
  
End Sub
Public Sub CreateAWorkbook()

Dim Asset_Id As String
Dim Current_Mark As String
Dim DateTimeStamp As String, WorkbookName As String

Call LeftClick(481, 38)
Call LeftClick(336, 69)
Asset_Id = Range("F2").Value
Current_Mark = Range("I2").Value

If IsEmpty(Range("F2").Value) = False And IsEmpty(Range("I2").Value) = False Then
MessageToDisplay = "The Asset id is : " & Asset_Id & " and current mark is: " & Current_Mark
MsgBox (MessageToDisplay)

Else
MessageToDisplay = "The Asset id is not present"
MsgBox (MessageToDisplay)

End If

End Sub
```

I am able to check the values but the left click is not working plus I do not know how to simply enter username on pop-up, as that pop-up is not the part of excel.

Can anyone please help , I am in super need of it?

Comment: Editing your question and placeing a picture of the form where you need to enter the user, the password and (probably) a button to click it, will maybe help. Theoretically, you should use `FindWindow` API (using the form Title/Caption, to obtain its handle, then `FindWindowEx` to identify the handler of text boxes (Edit type), `SendMessage` API to write text and the same API to click the button. But, you can better handle this issue if you have Spy++, or something similar. It is not mandatory that the child windows to belong to the main window and need to see the hierarchy...

Comment: I cannot post a picture due to company policy. How can I use FindWindow, FindWindowEx,SendMessage ? Can you please elaborate the use of these three?

Comment: I was using SetCursorPos for single left click. I used it separately and I was working fine as expected. But while calling in different subroutine, it is not working. Can you also please suggest for this?